# LDAP Bulk rename possible?

Tags: ldap, openldap

Is it possible to do bulk rename of uid's (or any attributes) using LDAP commands.

For ex: I want to rename all entries with attribute 
uid=`*@old.com   to    uid=`*@new.com

Thanks,
David.

Answer (score 1):

There is no native LDAP support for a "bulk rename". Some ideas are:

1. Export the desired objects to LDIF, change the objects in the exported file using the tool of your choice (perl, awk, python, vi). Add the changed objects, then delete the (now) misnamed objects.
2. Construct an LDAP transaction wherein a series of modify DN operations are executed in a single transaction. In an LDAP transaction, either every operation works or the whole thing fails. See also: [LDAP: Transactions](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5805.txt)

Other schemes might be devised.